# How to enable CORS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http-headers, cors

I have two sites: local :20279/ and local :54220. 54220 is opened through out IFrame from 20279. After user click on button, the IFrame will be closed and I get data inside the 52220. I read about how to enable CORS, and this is what I did in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And this code in file js to read data inside IFrame

```
function dialog_close() {
    dialog(false, '');

    getValueFromIFrame("if-dialog", "status");
}

function getValueFromIFrame(idIFrame, idField) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(idIFrame);
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var value = innerDoc.getElementById(idField).value;
    alert(value);
    //return value;
}
```

And this is what I get from browser:

```
Blocked a frame with origin 20279 from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:54220". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. <br/>
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:20279" from accessing a frame with origin 54220. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

My question is: how do I make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with CORS.  You will need read up on the Web Messaging API, as you will need to utilize it to communicate with iframes on differing origins.

Comment: @RayNicholus: It works. Thanks for your help. May you post an answer which I can mark it?

Comment: If you have a working solution, you should post the code for that as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your reponse must be set to the exact value sent in the Origin header of the HTTP request, a * is not enough.

Comment: 1.) Usually, a "*" is perfectly okay.  Your statement is only true if the cross-origin request is a credentialed request.  2.) This question does not involve CORS.  The OP is mistaken about that.